# When I set client side less compilation shows me error

Tags: magento2, error, css, compilation, js-css

Hello I am new in developing in Magento, I have Magento CE. When I set the Front End development workflow to type client side less compilation shows me an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to
>   Magento\Developer
>   \Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FrontendCompilation::processContent()
>   must be an instance of
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\FallbackContext, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\Context given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FrontendCompilation.php
>   on line 90 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FrontendCompilation.php:107
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FrontendCompilation.php(90):
>   Magento\Developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FrontendCompilation->processContent('e6a662994948b56...',
>   '@import 'source...', '',
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\Context)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\PreprocessorStrategy.php(74): Magento\Developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FrontendCompilation->
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-developer\Model\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FrontendCompilation.php
>   on line 107

My mode is set it to developer mode.
Any consideration for that?

Comment: did you try setup upgrade command?

Comment: yes I try it. It doesn't work !!

Comment: try after delete files from `generated` folder.

Answer (score 5):

Just check if you have "CSS Settings" -> "Merge CSS Files" set to No, and then try switching to Client side

Use this command to set css minification to NO

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0
```

Thanks for this @s-adamson answer it saved many times.

Comment: If developer mode is crashing, then you can't reach these settings using the front end (the section is hidden in production mode) so you'll need to use the command line: `php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0`

Comment: @SAdamson Thanks it saved

Answer (score 0):

Remove the content of : `var/view_preprocessed/`

Remove the content of : `pub/static/`

run : `php bin/magento cache:clean`

run : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

run : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: when I try php bin/magento setup:di:compile it shows                                                The directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/generated/code/Temando/Shipping/Model" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/generated/code/Temando/Shipping/Model): Directory not empty

Comment: clean the content of `generated/` then restart the steps

Comment: Well, it works but I loose the front end and I see only a blank page. After that I try the setup:upgrade and it shows me again the same problem.. How I can restart magento ?  It was a fresh install.

Comment: I don't know if there is some way to retart Magento, you need to remove your custom modules, theme. otherwise you reinstall a new Magento

Comment: It 's seems so difficult to develop in magneto I do one change and crash for ever..