# I enabled less compilation mode to client side, after that I am getting error, how can I resolve

Tags: magento2, less-compilation

I enabled less compilation mode from server to client side, after that I am getting error.
I tried putting magento in different modes.

and I also tried [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246955/when-i-set-client-side-less-compilation-shows-me-error) but it didn't worked.

[image]

Comment: From what i can see you are either passing a interger or array into strpos function were it expects a string my recommendation would be to find which module/theme file is causing this issue and that will give more more information as to the actions you need to take. please look at the system/exception logs for further reference to the possible source of the problem.

Comment: What Magento version you got and what PHP version does Magento run ? Because this looks like PHP version incompatibility .

Comment: @VyacheslavShmal php 7.4 and magento 2.4.1